# How to double escape double quotations marks using regex in a pair of double quotation marks

Tags: regex, escaping

I am using regex to match a pattern of user input. `username` is a variable storing user's input username. 
The regex should be able to match: user, space, optional quotation mark, user-entered username, optional quotation mark, optional other stuff.

What I have so far: `pattern="^user ${username}\b.*$"`

What I have tried: `pattern="^user (\\")?${username}(\\")?\b.*$"`to double escape double quotation mark here but it was not working.

Examples of matching:

`user "myusername" I really don't know how to solve this`

`user myusername Please help me with this`

`user "myusername123"`

`user moreusernames And yeah this is the question`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&quot;` can be used as a double quotation mark inside of double quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

```
^user ["]?(.*)["]?.*
```

check this website for testing: https://regex101.com

- start with user
- space
- the double quotes can be literally used in the group (question mark meaning 0 or 1)
- the (.*) is where your variable will come in syntax of your language e.g. in some languages <>
- followed by double quotes again
- .* meaning any character, any num of times